# How to set an environment variable with the value that return in a text file?

Tags: batch-file

The text file will be having just one word("1234" or "password" ), now I'm looking for a way to give this content of the text file to an environment variable

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to read one line you can also use `set /p`.

```
<myFile.txt set /p var=
echo %var%
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below for loop syntax. Replace filename with your filename, or environmental variable.
If this code is supposed to be put inside a batch file, replace % with %%, as %%t.

```
for /F %t in (filename) Do (
    echo %t
    :: Do whatever else you want to do with %t
)
```